# Using fgets and sscanf in C messed up the program after loop

Tags: c, function, fgets, scanf

I'm programming a tic tac toe game in C.

Everything seems to be going okay, but I like to implement error handling techniques for programs like this in case a user inputs bad data.

I ask the user to input a number between 1-9 to fill a slot on the tic tac toe graph. When I used fgets and sscanf together, it ran well during the first game. Then, when a user selected 'Y' or 'y' to continue playing a new game, it seemed as if none of the variable values refreshed, and it was basically causing chaos within the program.

Any tips?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
int printmatch(int array[3][3]);
int check(int array[3][3]);
char y;
char Y;
int complacer = 0;
int complacer2 = 0;

int main()
{
  do
  {

    int fill = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int slot = 0;
    int array[3][3];
    array[0][0] = 0;
    array[0][1] = 0;
    array[0][2] = 0;
    array[1][0] = 0;
    array[2][0] = 0;
    array[1][1] = 0;
    array[2][1] = 0;
    array[1][2] = 0;
    array[2][2] = 0;
    srand(time(NULL ));
    printmatch(array);
    char line[20];

    do
    {
      do
      {
        tryagain: printf("\nEnter Position 1-9(from left to right):");

        //I was using fgets and sscanf as an error handling technique incase user inputs incompatible data type, but after the 1st game is over, it seems this code messes up the functionality of the program
        //fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
        //sscanf(line,"%d",&slot);

        //when I just use scanf for data input, all is fine, but limited error handling
        scanf("%d", &slot);
        if (slot > 9 || slot < 1)
        {
          printf("Incorrect data input! Try again. \n");
        }

      } while (!(slot > 0 && slot < 10));

      switch (slot)
      {
      case 1:
        if (array[0][0] == -1)
        {
          printf("\nWoops, try again!");
          goto tryagain;
        }
        array[0][0] = 1;
        check(array);
        break;
      case 2:
        if (array[1][0] == -1)
        {
          printf("\nWoops, try again!");
          goto tryagain;
        }
        array[1][0] = 1;
        check(array);
        break;
      case 3:
        if (array[2][0] == -1)
        {
          printf("\nWoops, try again!");
          goto tryagain;
        }
        array[2][0] = 1;
        check(array);
        break;
      case 4:
        if (array[0][1] == -1)
        {
          printf("\nWoops, try again!");
          goto tryagain;
        }
        array[0][1] = 1;
        check(array);
        break;
      case 5:
        if (array[1][1] == -1)
        {
          printf("\nWoops, try again!");
          goto tryagain;
        }
        array[1][1] = 1;
        check(array);
        break;
      case 6:
        if (array[2][1] == -1)
        {
          printf("\nWoops, try again!");
          goto tryagain;
        }
        array[2][1] = 1;
        check(array);
        break;
      case 7:
        if (array[0][2] == -1)
        {
          printf("\nWoops, try again!");
          goto tryagain;
        }
        array[0][2] = 1;
        check(array);
        break;
      case 8:
        if (array[1][2] == -1)
        {
          printf("\nWoops, try again!");
          goto tryagain;
        }
        array[1][2] = 1;
        check(array);
        break;
      case 9:
        if (array[2][2] == -1)
        {
          printf("\nWoops, try again!");
          goto tryagain;
        }
        array[2][2] = 1;
        check(array);
        break;

      }

      if (array[0][0] != 0 && array[0][1] != 0 && array[0][2] != 0
          && array[1][0] != 0 && array[2][0] != 0 && array[1][1] != 0
          && array[2][1] != 0 && array[1][2] != 0 && array[2][2] != 0)
      {
        check(array);

        if (check(array) == 1)
        {
          printf("The user wins!\n");
        }

        else if (check(array) == -1)
        {
          printf("The computer wins.\n");
        }

        else
        {
          printmatch(array);
          printf("It's a draw!\n");
        }

        goto done;
      }
      ++fill;
      label:

      complacer = rand() % 3;
      complacer2 = rand() % 3;

      if (array[complacer][complacer2] == 0)
      {
        array[complacer][complacer2] = -1;
        check(array);
      }

      else
        goto label;

      ++fill;

      printmatch(array);
      int fullcheck = check(array);
      if (fullcheck == 1)
      {
        printf("The user wins!");
        break;
      }

      if (fullcheck == -1)
      {
        printf("The computer wins.");
        break;
      }

      if (fill > 9)
        break;
    } while (fill < 10);
    done: printf("\nDo you want to continue? Y/N\n");
    scanf("%c %c", &y, &Y);
  } while ((Y == 'Y' || Y == 'y'));
  getchar();
  return 0;

}
int printmatch(int array[3][3])
{

  int i;
  int j;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
      printf("%d\t", array[j][i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

  }
}

int check(int array[3][3])
{
  int settle;

  if (array[0][0] == 1 && array[1][1] == 1 && array[2][2] == 1)
  {
    settle = 1;

  }

  else if (array[0][0] == -1 && array[1][1] == -1 && array[2][2] == -1)
  {

    settle = -1;

  }

  if (array[0][0] == 1 && array[0][1] == 1 && array[0][2] == 1)
  {
    settle = 1;

  }
  else if (array[0][0] == -1 && array[0][1] == -1 && array[0][2] == -1)
  {

    settle = -1;

  }

  if (array[0][2] == 1 && array[1][2] == 1 && array[2][2] == 1)
  {
    settle = 1;

  }
  else if (array[0][2] == -1 && array[1][2] == -1 && array[2][2] == -1)
  {

    settle = -1;

  }

  if (array[0][1] == 1 && array[1][1] == 1 && array[2][1] == 1)
  {
    settle = 1;

  }
  else if (array[0][1] == -1 && array[1][1] == -1 && array[2][1] == -1)
  {

    settle = -1;

  }

  if (array[1][0] == 1 && array[1][1] == 1 && array[1][2] == 1)
  {
    settle = 1;

  }
  else if (array[1][0] == -1 && array[1][1] == -1 && array[1][2] == -1)
  {
    settle = -1;

  }

  if (array[0][0] == 1 && array[1][0] == 1 && array[2][0] == 1)
  {
    settle = 1;

  }
  else if (array[1][0] == -1 && array[1][1] == -1 && array[1][2] == -1)
  {
    settle = -1;

  }

  if (array[2][0] == 1 && array[1][1] == 1 && array[0][2] == 1)
  {
    settle = 1;

  }
  else if (array[1][0] == -1 && array[1][1] == -1 && array[1][2] == -1)
  {
    settle = -1;

  }
  if (array[2][0] == 1 && array[2][1] == 1 && array[2][2] == 1)
  {
    settle = 1;

  }

  else if (array[2][0] == -1 && array[2][1] == -1 && array[2][2] == 1)
  {
    settle = -1;

  }
  return settle;
}
```

Comment: `int array[3][3] = { { 0 } };`...

Comment: Also, the nested-ifs-in-nested-switches are horrible. Use loops, integer division and modulo arithmetic, etc...

Comment: I notice that you're using `goto` for error handling. I strongly advise against this. There are many reasons, and in fact there are many columns, papers, screeds, and rants against this (and the occasional article in favor) but basically, it boils down to this: it adds a level of confusion and complexity, and it disrupts the normal flows of control that anyone looking at your code will expect to find. (There _are_ valid use-cases for `goto`, and I've worked with production code that used it, but until you are a genuine expert and really know what you're doing, you shouldn't even consider it.)

Answer (score 1):

User input is *evil*.  When you want a number, someone types 'A'.  You want a 'y' or 'n' and you get a input of dozens of letters.  Kudos for trying to improve your coding with defensive error handling.

When using `sscanf()` or `scanf()`, etc., be sure to check the results

```
int result;  
result = sscanf(buffer, "%this %that ...", &var1);  
if (result != ExpectedResult) // handle error
```

Mixing `fgets()` with `getchar()` and `scanf()` is likely to confuse the issue.  Recommend not using `fgets()` with those 2.  `fgets()` is line orientated, `scanf()` often stops before consuming the new-line.

Its fun to only type a 'Y' or 'y' to continue, but using a "letter & enter_key" combo is not so bad and it is easier to sort out at first.

The `fgets()` `sscanf()` pair may have caused a hiccup, but in the end it easier to sort out.  Recommend returning to that style and checking the result of the `sscanf()`.

Example

```
scanf("%d", &slot);
```

Here you do not know if the user typed any number before pressing 'Enter'.  Even is the user did type a number, your scanf() consumes the leading spaces and the digits, but leaves the 'Enter' for the *next* input function.  Instead:

```
int ScanCount;
const char *prompt = "\nEnter Position 1-9(from left to right):";
do {
  fputs(prompt, stdout);
  prompt = "Incorrect data input! Try again. \n"; // For the maybe next time around
  if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) {
    // Standard input is closed or some grievous I/O error, let's go home.
    return 0;
  }
  ScanCount = sscanf(line,"%d",&slot);
} while ((ScanCount != 1) || (slot < 1) || slot > 9));
```

---

BTW: Here is a little trick to test if *extra* text was entered after a number like "9z".  Replace `ScanCount = ... slot > 9));` with

```
char c;
ScanCount = sscanf(line,"%d%[^\n]",&slot, &c);
} while ((ScanCount != 1) || (slot < 1) || slot > 9));  // still ScanCount != 1
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to C programming and have yet to grasp what is really happening behind the scenes. Your explanation was fairly easy to understand, thank you. The only line I don't understand is the if(fgets(line... etc. What exactly does this do?

Comment: It's pedantic, but getting data from `stdin` _could_ end (the user console is close) or fail (a broken pipe).  Should this happen, `fgets()` returns NULL and the `if()` could deal with that.  As you are new, these are not a likely concerns.  Suggest looking into the reasons why `fgets()` could return NULL later in your coding experience.  Happy trailings and welcome to SO.